# Connect and downlaod content with socket in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sockets, download

Hi I want to use socket programming for downlaoding HTML from the server.
Any body can give such a sample code.

Comment: Surely there's a higher-level API for HTML over HTTP? I think the real question here is probably closer to: "what's the best way to access web content under iOS?"

Comment: Actually I want to establish socket connection to streaming server and want to download its content like image,.css,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The framework you're looking for is here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html

Sockets would be needless headache in this case.

Comment: Actually I want to establish socket connection to streaming server and want to download its content like image,.css,etc

Comment: You can run multiple http calls simultaneously.  Anyway, if you're hooked on using sockets you can look at the NSSocket interface.